# Convert a list's part into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, loops

## I have a list 'list_of_categories_train' having values:

```
0                                      [Men, Tops, T-shirts]
1          [Electronics, Computers & Tablets, Components ...
2                            [Women, Tops & Blouses, Blouse]
3                   [Home, Home DÃ©cor, Home DÃ©cor Accents]
4                                [Women, Jewelry, Necklaces]
                                 ...                        
1048570                                 [Kids, Other, Other]
1048571           [Other, Daily & Travel items, Health Care]
1048572    [Women, Athletic Apparel, Pants, Tights, Leggi...
1048573                       [Men, Shoes, Fashion Sneakers]
1048574                    [Kids, Toys, Dolls & Accessories]
Name: category_name, Length: 1048575, dtype: object
```

I need to pick 1st word of each list and put it into dataframe. But it takes hours. what is the fastest way to do that?
My Code is:

```
i=0
while i <= len(list_of_categories_train)  :  
    data_train['noOfCategories']= list_of_categories_train[i][0]
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list_of_categories_train` is your series, *and if each element in the series is a list*, you can try:

```
data_train['noOfCategories'] = list_of_categories_train.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
data_train['noOfCategories'] = [x[0] for x in list_of_categories_train]
```

Slowier:

```
data_train['noOfCategories'] = list_of_categories_train.str[0]
```

Comment: Through this code I get 1st letter, I need 1st word i.e Men,electonics ...

Comment: @MuhammadAffan - What is `print (type(data_train.loc[0, 'category_name']))` ?

Comment: @MuhammadAffan - use `data_train['noOfCategories'] = [x[0] for x in list_of_categories_train]`

Comment: It seems `apply` works well for the OP but the 1st suggestion may be faster for very large datasets.